# How do I modify source code within the context of a Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I would like to write a Maven plugin which does a simple find and replace within specific source files during a build. Is this even possible?

Comment: I think yes, why not? Just bind it to phase that happens before compilation and you should be good to go.

Comment: additionally make sure your plugin adds the output directory of your modified sources to the compile path (see MavenProject.addCompileSourceRoot() method) so that the compiler plugin knows there's another source folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should read [Guide to Developing Java Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html).

Maybe instead of creating a new plugin, you can use an existing one.

Example [com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <file>FILE PATH (example: ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/index.html)</file>
        <token>SEARCHED TEXT (example: .css)</token>
        <value>REPLACEMENT (example: .min.css)</value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you want to replace XML data, then you should use [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) sections:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <file>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</file>
        <token><![CDATA[SEARCHED TEXT (example: <foo>)]]></token>
        <value><![CDATA[REPLACEMENT (example: <foo2>)]]></value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```